# payment gateway integration with emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, payment-gateway, hapi.js

I have build an eCommerce website using emberjs with ember-data-1.8.0.On Api side i am using Hapijs.
I have integrated Payu payment gateway with it,but i am not able to handle response send by payu.After payment payu send a post response to given route of ember, but How will i handle this response and will get all payload so i can send request to my hapi server.
i have no clue how to do it, if there is some doc or example of integrating payment gateway and emberjs, please mention it also. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ember is a client side framework, Payu will not be able to send a "post" request to ember it may perform it on your Hapijs backend however. Then you have many options to check events on  your backend from your frontend for example through sockets or via a setInterval which queries a given page every N seconds.